Failed to connect to Postgresql database in Visual Studio
I created a simple .NET8 MAUI app to test a connection to a postgresql database before integrating that code into my main app.
However, the connection is failing.

I installed Npgsql through the nuget package manager.
Filepath: C:\Users\owner.nuget\packages\npgsql\8.0.5\lib
filepath to Npgsql.dll

The Npgsql package is appropriately refernced in the .csproj file:
csproj file

Then I have a simple content page (xaml and cs) that displays a page with a button that tries to connect to the databased (that i've already created)
xaml database connection test

cs database connection test


Anyone have a clue whats going on here? Been stuck on this for a while now...
